# Multiple master replication to single slave in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am having trouble in my database design. I would like to accomplish all the instances below:

1.) Multi-Master and Single Slave.

2.) Rename database in slave.(Server1 and Server has diff datasets)

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O39HN.png)

Currently i can replicate database by 1 master per slave. But i can't do it the way i want it (Just like the above picture). I read about Multi-source replication in mysql 5.7 but it says that it is not advisable for production. And i don't think that was i'm looking for.

I am using ubuntu, nginx and mysql. How can i accomplish this design?

Answer (score 0):

The Main reason why this not workout is  *CHANGE MASTER* command.
This only allows you to set one Master as a source to read

[here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40379/single-slave-multiple-master-mysql-replication) is the full explation of why its not succesfull.