# Mysql finding the updated slave

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave

I've set up simple MySQL replication: 1 master and 3 slaves.

How to find out in those 3 slaves which is the latest and perfectly sync before the master server is down? Let's say I don't have access on the server because it is totally damage.

Comment: should i get the difference between the exec_master_log_pos and Read_Master_Log_Pos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slave works with 2 threads. The Slave_IO thread and the Slave_SQL thread.

The Slave_IO thread is responsible for reading the binary log from the master and writing what he read in the relay log on the slave.

The Slave_SQL thread is responsible for executing the statements in the relay log.

A slave is up to date **not** when `Seconds_behind_master` is `0` (I'm talking about the output of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`), but when

- `Relay_Master_log_file` is the same as `Master_log_file` and
- `Exec_Master_log_pos` is the same as `Read_Master_log_pos`

Again, in other words `Master_Log_File` and `Read_Master_Log_Pos` is what the slave is fetching from the master.
And `Relay_Master_Log_File` and `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` is what is being executed in master "coordinates".
And, just for completeness but not really interesting, `Relay_Log_File` and `Relay_Log_Pos` is what is being executed from the relay log.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.It gives me a real head start in database. I'm just hoping that you can also help me with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374465/multiple-master-replication-to-single-slave-in-mysql